# Unify the flag indicator and flag queue between meta and main sites

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderators, per-site-meta, flag-queue

The flag queue on meta sites is separate from the flag queue on main sites. It's one more thing to check, and it's low-volume so there's no incentive to check it often because it would be empty most of the time. Yet sometimes flags indicate that urgent action is needed (e.g. flamewar in progress).

In addition, as meta sites have rather lower activity, this means moderators can sometimes go for a while without visiting the meta sites, leaving flags to linger. This is especially true since moderators receive a notification on the main site for each new meta question, so in the absence of such notification, there is little reason to think something big is happening on meta and thus to visit the meta site and find out about a flag.

Please unify the flag queue between the main site and the meta site. I think putting meta flags in a separate category (like there are now categories for spam, not an answer, etc.) would be sufficient to distinguish them when needed.

MSO before the MSE split is obviously a special case.