# In the flag queue, make it more obvious when there are flags on the per-site-meta

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, per-site-meta, flag-queue

The flag queue for moderators looks like this (when empty):

[image: flag queue]

Even it may not be obvious to the uninitiated, my attention as a moderator is mainly on the left side (where the red text is), because this is where flags are listed. If this space is empty (as in the picture), this usually means that there is nothing to do. The sidebar is hardly ever relevant to most moderators (except on SO, where sorting flags by type makes sense).
There is one exception: If there is a flag on the respective per-site meta, it is shown there (which was requested
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109827/255554),
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277171/255554), and 
[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225054/255554)).
This also is the case in the example.

However, due to its location and due to the rarity of meta flags, this indicator is easy to miss.
The vicinity to the flag number in the header probably doesn’t help.
Moreover, moderators get alerted when there is a flag in the queue, and thus there is no reason for them to go to the above site when there is no flag.
Therefore it can easily happen that moderators fail to notice that there is something on meta demanding their attention¹.
Indeed, I have a flag on one per-site meta that has been pending for more than two months (and I don’t think it’s because the moderators can’t make up their mind).

I therefore propose that the existence of Meta flags should draw more optical attention.

---

<sup>¹ Moderators could also directly notice the flags by visiting meta, but then most per-site metas have a very low activity and moderators get alerted of every question there anyway, so there is little need for them to do this regularly.</sup>

Comment: Don't forget that when you go to your meta site there'll be an indicator of the meta flags in the same place as the main site flags.

Comment: @ChrisF: See my edit.